# datetime query in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have to write a query to get rows where date is like current date.
I don't want to compare the the time part but only date part.
Like today's date is 2014-05-03
but in table its in datetime as 2014-05-03 10:08:22

i tried [[http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp]](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp%5d)

but could not do anything..

my query is like

```
select *from dbo.param where cvdatetime like '2014-05-03%';
```

but its does not work although if i use

```
select *from dbo.param where cvdatetime like '%2014%';
```

it works so i don't get why "like" can't work in the previous case

i just want to compare the date part only not the time part..

like in c# i will take the current date as

```
 string today_n = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

which will give only today's date
the query will be like

```
string query="select *from dbo.param where cvdatetime like '" + today_n + "%'"
```

what is the correct way?
also i want that whatever be the system date format query should work like even if system date time format is dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt the query should work how can i ensure this?

Adding new requirement what if I need to check date hh:mm: only not seconds

i.e, 2014-05-04 12:00: part only not seconds part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `like` as such on `datetime` column.

Use the below:

```
select * from dbo.param where convert(varchar, cvdatetime, 120) like '%2014%';
```

As, far your second question is concerned, you'll have to use parameterized queries to avoid sql injection attacks.

Comment: it works but can u explain the query especially 120 thing used.

Comment: also can i use ur query to get like date and hh:mm (not seconds)

Comment: also when it returns the result in cvdatetime section it is showing correct date but not time is it converting the time like cvdatetime is 2014-05-04 12:02:00 but its is actually showing after executing query as 2014-05-04 00:02:00

Comment: @Vipasha, you can still get `cvdatetime `as such since you are selecting `*`

Comment: yes but i hv extended my question a bit like now i also want to compare the time part but till date hh:mm can you suggest something for that..

Comment: put that in a separate question in a clear way, after accepting this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server 2005 or later, just convert the `datetime` to `date`:

```
select *
from dbo.param
where cast(cvdatetime as date) = '2014-05-03';
```

Do not think about dates as strings.  Think of them as dates, with the string format only used for output purposes.  Or, if you have to make an analogy to another type, think numbers.  As an example, go into Excel, put a date into a cell.  Nicely format it.  Then set another cell equal to the value of the first cell (`=A1` for example).  Format that as a number and you will see some strange number, probably in the range of about 40,000.  Excel stores dates as number of days since 1970-01-01.  SQL has a similar (but different) storage mechanism.

Comment: Actually, the `DATE` datatype was introduced in SQL Server **2008** (not 2005)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for the current date:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.param
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, cvdatetime)  = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```